# How to wrap content into a Frame inside a Grid so frame doesn't expand to fit it's parent size?

Tags: c#, maui

```cs
this.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection()
{
    new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Star },
    new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Star },
    new RowDefinition() { Height = 1 },
};

this.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
{
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) },
    new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
};

this.subjectLabel = new Label();
this.subjectLabel.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
this.subjectLabel.MaxLines = 1;
this.Add(subjectLabel, 0, 0);

this.messageLabel = new Label();
this.messageLabel.TextTransform = TextTransform.None;
this.messageLabel.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
this.messageLabel.MaxLines = 1;
this.Add(messageLabel, 0, 1);

this.formsCount = new Label();
formsCount.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 3, 0);

var documentIcon = new Label
{
    FontFamily = Theme.Active.Fonts.IconsFamily,
    Text = Theme.Fonts.FontAwesome5.FileAlt,
    TextColor = Theme.Active.Colours.Passive,
    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    FontSize = 16,
};

var iconStack = new StackLayout()
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    BackgroundColor = Colors.Red,
    Children =
    {
        formsCount,
        documentIcon
    }
};

var iconFrame = new Frame
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 100, 100),
    CornerRadius = 20,
    Padding = 0,
    Content = iconStack,
};

this.Add(iconFrame, 1, 0);
Grid.SetRowSpan(iconFrame, 2);
```

currently I've got the following view:

[image]

and I want it to look like this:

[image]
(red color is StackLayout's background)

In other words, I need the frame to be the size of its content (StackLayout) plus some small padding.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried creating the desired layout in XAML directly? 
I would guess once you have that looking the way you want it, it will inform the way you go about creating it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found some issues about Maui Frame size on Github, I recommend to use  [Maui Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-7.0) instead. The usage of Border is almost the same.

```
    var iconBorder = new Border
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 100, 100),
        StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle
        {
            CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(20, 20, 20, 20)
        },
        Padding = 5,
        Content = iconStack,
    };
```

And I agree with Scott Solmer. You may find it easier if you use a XAML. So I also write a XAML for your case. You could have a try if you want.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="1" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Label Text="Subject" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
   <Label Text="Message" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
 
   <Border  VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
          HorizontalOptions="Center" 
          BackgroundColor = "Yellow" Padding="3">
       <Border.StrokeShape>
           <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20,20,20,20"/>
       </Border.StrokeShape>
       <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    >
           <Label Text="1" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
           <Label Text="23" FontSize="16"
                  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
       </StackLayout>
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

Hope it works for you.